# how to upgrade libvirt?

Tags: redhat, openstack, libvirt, openstack-nova

I'm trying to install openstack on RHEL 6.2. Following installation guide from openstack.org, I'm using the command:

```
yum install openstack-nova openstack-glance
```

After resolved many dependencies, I got the final error:

```
Error: Package: openstack-nova-compute-2012.2.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
       Requires: libvirt >= 0.9.6
       Installed: libvirt-0.9.4-23.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201111171049.x86_64/6.2)
           libvirt = 0.9.4-23.el6
```

I installed libvirt 0.9.4 from the RHEL 6.2 DVD, but it seems I have to upgrade libvirt 0.9.6. How to do the upgrade? Or where can I download libvirt 0.9.6 rpm? Or can I use yum to upgrade libvirt?

Comment: try yum update, and make sure it is updating against the RHN on-line sources and not the DVD media.  then yes upgrade from yum.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for the RHEL6 or CentOS 6 rpms from 
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=1&srodzaj=1&dl=40&search=libvirt&dist[]=74&dist[]=79&dist[]=0&field[]=1&field[]=2

Also, it looks like libvirt has got a lot of dependencies, so after downloading the appropriate libvirt-0.9.xxx.rpm, you could try

yum localinstall libvirt-0.9.xxx.rpm

if even after that you have some dependencies missing, you might want to download them manually like the libvirt rpm itself, managing which can soon start to become a nightmare!